# cannot add navigation dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am trying to Add Navigation in my project but its showing failed to add Navigation dependency,

when i click on 'ok' in the window to add these now , its showing failed to add dependency and my navigation xml editor is not visible

build gradle project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common
```

to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

```
  ext {
      version_navigation = "2.3.0"
       kotlin_version = "1.4.32"
  }

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}}

 task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir}
```

build gradle module:

```
 plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'

}

 android {
compileSdkVersion 32
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

buildFeatures{
    dataBinding true
    viewBinding true
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.exampleko"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard- 
rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
 }

dependencies {

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.2'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

//navigation
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.2'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is the following:

In the `build.gradle` (project version), find where you have the `ext { }` and put this inside:

```
navigationVersion = "2.3.0"
```

Then, in the `build.gradle` (module), inside the `dependencies { }` you have to put theese two dependencies:

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigationVersion"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigationVersion"
```

And finally, **Sync project with gradle files** and **Rebuild** it to make sure everything is okay.

You can change the navigationVersion to the one that you are using on the project gradle.

Then follow [this](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-add-navigation?index=..%2F..android-kotlin-fundamentals#0) codelab if you encounter some extra problems.

Comment: i face this error :  Build file 'D:\ExampleKo\app\build.gradle' line: 55

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'navigationVersion' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.                                        in the first dependency which you get

Comment: Can you update your question with your gladle files please?

Comment: Try to replace 'navigationVersion on dependencies with the version

Comment: yes i replace that with 2.4.2

Comment: no no, i mean like this: androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.2

Comment: yes i do that ,and the problem for adding navigation not gone

Comment: please, update your question with all your gradle (module)

Comment: yes, i do that .

Comment: I can't find what's wrong, I have almost the same

Comment: I'm surprised too , i spend many hours on this problem What do you suggest me

Comment: create a new project, and add first the navigation dependencies, and see if it breaks or not. If you do that and it works, do everything there.